# Phone call activity Shows "Red Cross Mark" on top of form after Saving the activity Without any error msg he in MS CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing one issue in Phone call activity. After saving the phone call activity record in crm, on the top of the form a red cross mark shows by system without any error message:
[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: Are there any onLoad or onSave JavaScript event handlers on the form? The banner could be set by [setFormNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_setFormNotification) with a `level` of `"ERROR"`.

Comment: I have one javascript on form load but i have disabled it. still getting same error.

Comment: Have you checked Developer Tools for any js scripts errors?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. If "Call To" contains Contacts OR Account then in the communication information section  phone  should be "allow" in contacts and account. In my case it was "Not Allowed"  that's the reason red cross mark appearing in phone call activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. I made an unsupported fix waiting for a real one: http://xrmmtl.com/crm-2016-phone-call-blank-notification/

Comment: I have figured out the issue. If "Call To" contains Contacts OR Account then in the communication information section  phone  should be "allow" in contacts and account record. In my case it was "Not Allowed"  that's the reason red cross mark appearing in phone call activity.